# Is there a way make python alternately reassign variables, while keeping one locked alternatively?

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to solve the problem of whether a string is balanced or not (to check whether a string has equal number of unique characters e.g "ab" has an equal number of 'a' and 'b', so it will return "Yes", while "cdc" has 1 more 'c' than 'd', so it will return "No"), and I thought of a solution that would require an alternating variable.

For instance in the code below:

```
def balanced(string):
    string_list = [x for x in string]
    number_of_letter1 = 0
    for letter in string_list:
        current_letter = letter
        for number in range(len(string_list)):
            if string_list[number] == current_letter:
                number_of_letter1 += 1
                string_list.pop(number)
            if number_of_letter1 != number_of_letter2:
                return "No"
        number_of_letter2 = number_of_letter1.copy()
        number_of_letter1 = 0
    return "Yes"
```

I'm trying to count the number for every letter that appears in the string, assigning the current letter I'm at to current_letter. Then I would count the times the letter appears and increase number_of_letter1 by 1. The next step is where the problem comes in :( . I want to have number_of_letter2 be a copy of number_of_letter1, so I can compare the (new number_of_letter1 in the next loop) with the (number_of_letter1 of the previous loop, which is number_of_letter2). However, only for the first loop, number_of_letter2 does not exist, thus creating the variable used before assignment error.

I think it can be resolved by locking number_of_letter1 in the first loop, then changing number_of_letter2, compare it with number_of_letter1, then vice versa with every alternating loop (if that is even possible). If not, is there any way to fix the code above so it works with the logic mentioned?

I'm aware of another solution to this problem, involving keeping the number_of_letter1 constant, while number_of_letter2 dynamic, and repeatedly comparing the number_of_letter2 to the constant number_of_letter1. However, if the above proposed solution works, I **think** it would be more efficient than the latter, so I'm quite curious of ways around the error.

Thanks a bunch for taking the time to read! I'll try my best to explain more clearly if any of my explanations of my thoughts weren't that clear.

Comment: Look up a tutorial on how to use dictionaries. After you have found out how to implement this using dictionaries, you can go on and use `collections.Counter`.

Comment: Some more notes: You can iterate over the characters of a string directly. `pop`ing from a list removes an element from it, do not do that while iterating over said list.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa Ah, that seems to be the common solution from another commenter as well. I guess Codecademy only taught me the very basics of dictionaries, haha. Thanks!

and yep i'm aware of iterating directly on a string, I just thought I could have an easier time to pop the list if it was in index form. And tip noted, thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work:

```
from collections import Counter

def balanced(string):
    return len(set(Counter(string).values())) <= 1
```

The `collections.Counter` collects the counts of all chars in a single iteration. Then you test how many distinct counts there are.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach:

```py
def is_balanced(string):
    if len(string)<1:
        return False

    unique_letters = set(string)
    n_occurances = 0
    for letter in unique_letters:
        n_occurances_this = string.count(letter)

        if n_occurances == 0:
            n_occurances = n_occurances_this
        elif n_occurances_this != n_occurances:
            return False
    
    return True
```

This code creates a set (unique list) of characters in string and checks number of occurrences of every character

Comment: Don't call `count` repeatedly on the same iterable.

Comment: @schwobaseggl It does not call `count` more than 1 time per unique letter. But I guess you can write `string.count(letter)` to a variable to make code more understandable. Will do

Comment: Not more than 1 time per unique letter. But multiple times on the same string, which is bad, as it can and should be avoided.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I think I get it. It's bad 'cause `count` will iterate through the same string every time. Then yes, the `Counter` way is more efficient. Thanks for the remark